# php MySQL loop within nested divs

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli, nested

I have a nested div in which I want to fetch data from my database. I have explained what I want below:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        **First Entry Here**
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        **Second Entry Here**
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        **Third Entry Here**
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        **FourthEntry Here**
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on...

I am literally confused right now and the solution is not clicking in my mind. I have this code so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$ic = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if(($ic%2) == 0) {
   $div1 = '<div class="row-fluid">';
   $div2 = '</div>';
}else{
   $div1 = '';
   $div2 = '';
} 
?>

<?=$div1;?>
    <div class="span6">
        <?=$row['userid'];?>
    </div>
<?=$div2;?>

<?php
$ic = $ic + 1;
}
?>
```

I have tried two while loops but it was outputting around 5000 lines of code.

Comment: What does that code generate? `span6` = `xyz` and  `row-fluid` =`abcd`?

Comment: It simply lists out the registered users. row-fluid is a row which has 2 horizontal divs (span6). Both span6 contains a user's info. So for example if I have total 10 users, then row-fluid should be generated only 5 times and each row-fluid should have 2 span6 inside with user's info.

Comment: It only generates 5 row-fluids for me. https://eval.in/448721

Comment: Yes, but the structure is changing. The row-fluid must contain 2 span6 inside it. Try to match the output with the structure that I've provided. It's completely different.

Comment: In other words, row-fluid's child element must be span6 and span6's parent element must be row-fluid. And there should be 2 span6 inside row-fluid. If you check the output, the first row-fuild contains only 1 span6 and the next span6 doesn't have row-fluid as it's parent element. I hope I'm not confusing all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amr Magdy logic is correct, however the solution didn't work out for me. I have now managed to fix it and if anyone else has the same situation may refer to the code below:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$ic = 0;
$temp = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = '<div class="span6">'.$row['userid'].'</div>';
    if(($ic%2) == 0) {
       echo '<div class="row-fluid">'.$temp;
    $temp = "";
    }else{
       echo $temp;
    }
    $ic = $ic + 1;
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ic = 0;
$temp = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp .= "<div class='span6'>".$row['user_id']."</div>";
    if ( $ic % 2  != 0 ){
        echo "<div class='row-fluid'>".$temp."<div>";
        $temp = "";
    }
    $ic++;
}
// in case the number of records are odd::
if ($temp != "" )
    echo "<div class='row-fluid'>".$temp."<div>";
```

Comment: Your logic is correct but the solution didn't work out for me. Though I managed to make it work by modifying it a bit. I'll post it if you'd like to comment.